# Filtrar resultado de um collection_select baseado na seleção de outro

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Preciso filtrar o resultado de bairros baseado na seleção de uma cidade. Eu tenho uma relação de has_many através do active record. É possível realizar este filtro sem ter o submit?

Nos models:

```
class Cidade < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bairros
end

class Bairro < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :cidade
end
```

Na view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :bairro, "Bairro:", class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <%= f.collection_select :bairro_id, @bairros, :id, :nome, {} , class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :cidade_id, "Cidade:",class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
     <%= f.collection_select :cidade_id, @cidades, :id, :nome, {} , class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim é possível. Utilizo um código parecido com [grouped_collection_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/grouped_collection_select)

Caso a lista seja muito extensa, ainda é possível adicionar um jquery por exemplo, para mudar a lista de acordo com a primeira seleção.

Segue meu exemplo:

```
<%= f.label :origin_id, "Estado" %>
<%= f.collection_select(:origin_id, State.all, :symbol, :name, {:include_blank => true}, {:class=> "form-control"}) %>

<%= f.label :origin_city_id, "Cidade" %>
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :origin_city_id, State.order(:name), :cities, :name, :name, :name, {include_blank: true}, {:class=> "form-control"} %>
```

Comment: Olá Cleber, agradeço muito a ajuda. Eu consegui criar o grouped collection, porém, ele sempre lista todos os bairros, indiferente da cidade selecionada. Conhece alguma forma de trazer somente os bairros filtrados pela cidade já selecionada?